# Example of a big SystemVerilog constraint

Tags: system-verilog

Can you give an example of a big and complex SystemVerilog constraint? The bigger the better, and preferably realistic. Perhaps some address calculation that also depends on a few other variables.

I am evaluating switching our IP to use SystemVerilog constraints, and my management wants to see how easy/hard it is to create/understand SystemVerilog constraints.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As I cannot comment on the previous post, and my suggested edit is rejected I can only add what looks like a new answer but isn't. Sigh!

Here is Subbdue's example edited to fix the following syntax errors:

1. SV `typedef enum {...} <name>;` syntax as opposed to OpenVera `enum <name> {...};` syntax
2. End enum declaration with `;`
3. Declare variable `channelNumber`
4. Declare `ipVersion` as `rand`
5. SV `<var> inside { [<min>:<max>] }` syntax as opposed to OpenVera `<var> in { min:max }` syntax
6. End expressions in `constraint`s with `;`
7. SV `->` syntax as opposed to OpenVera `=>` syntax
8. Fix typo `solver` -> `solve`
9. Fix typo `IPVx` -> `IPVX`

Fixed example:

```
class RandomConstraints;
    typedef enum {IPV4=2, IPV6, IPVX} IpVersionType;

    //Randomly iterate over values without repetition
    randc bit [7:0] cyclicCounter;
    //Regular random variables
    rand bit [15:0] destAddress;
    rand bit [15:0] sourceAddress;
    rand bit [15:0] numberOfPackets;
    rand bit [15:0] packetLength;
    rand bit [3:0] channelNumber;
    rand bit [7:0]  var1;
    rand bit [7:0]  var2;
    rand IpVersionType ipVersion;

    //Non-random variables that can be used to control constraints
    bit [15:0] minNumberOfPackets, maxNumberOfPackets;
    bit [15:0] minPacketLength, maxPacketLength;
    integer IPV4Weight, IPV6Weight;

    constraint cPacketLength {
        packetLength inside { [ minPacketLength : maxPacketLength ] };
    }
    constraint cChannelNumber {
        channelNumber inside {[0:1]};
    }
    // Assuming total weight adds up to 100
    constraint cIPVersionType {
        ipVersion dist { IPV4 := IPV4Weight, IPV6 := IPV6Weight,
          IPVX := (100 - IPV4Weight - IPV6Weight) };
    }
    //Probability of var1 being 1,2,3,4,5 in the ratio 1,2,4,4,4
    constraint cDist1 {
        var1 dist { 1 := 1, 2 := 2, [3:4] := 4 };
    }
    //Probability of var2 being 1,2,3,4,5 is in the ratio 1,2,4/3,4/3,4/3
    constraint cDist2 {
        var2 dist { 1 := 1, 2 := 2, [3:5] :/ 4 };
    }
    //Implication constraint - if(channelNum == i) then { ... }
    constraint cImplication {
        (channelNumber == 0) -> {
            destAddress inside {[0:200]};
            sourceAddress inside {[201:400]};
        }
        (channelNumber == 1) -> {
            destAddress inside {[201:400]};
            sourceAddress inside {[0:200]};
        }
    }
    //Controlling order of constraints solved using a constraint solver
    constraint order_solver {
        solve channelNumber before destAddress;
        solve channelNumber before sourceAddress;
    }

    function new();
        //Setting default min/max packets and min/max packet length
        minNumberOfPackets = 100;
        maxNumberOfPackets = 1000;
        minPacketLength = 128;
        maxPacketLength = 256;
        IPV4Weight = 50;
        IPV6Weight = 30;
    endfunction
endclass
```

Comment: Good job. Seemingly, I need 2k points to be eligible to review suggested edits (Even on my own posts :)) .. Since you took the pains to create a new post, I'll leave mine as is.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example, probably not big and complex but it should give you a realistic idea about how constraints can be used. Here you'll see the following concepts used:

1. **randc and rand** - Cylic and Non-Cyclic Random Variables
2. The two types of **Distributed Constraints**
3. Using if conditions within a constraint using the **Implication operator** ... *Address calculated depending on another variable*
4. **Constraint order solver**
5. Constraining the default range of a random variable in the constructor
6. Using an enumerated type in constraints

Hope this helps ... and watch for the comments in-line:

```
class RandomConstraints;
    enum IpVersionType {IPV4=2, IPV6, IPVx}

    //Randomly iterate over values without repetition
    randc bit [7:0] cyclicCounter;
    //Regular random variables
    rand bit [15:0] destAddress;
    rand bit [15:0] sourceAddress;
    rand bit [15:0] numberOfPackets;
    rand bit [15:0] packetLength;
    rand bit [7:0]  var1;
    rand bit [7:0]  var2;
    IpVersionType ipVersion;

    //Non-random variables that can be used to control constraints
    bit [15:0] minNumberOfPackets, maxNumberOfPackets;
    bit [15:0] minPacketLength, maxPacketLength;
    integer IPV4Weight, IPV6Weight;

    constraint cPacketLength {
        packetLength in { minPacketLength : maxPacketLength }
    }
    constraint cChannelNumber {
        channelNumber in {0:1}
    }
    constraint cIPVersionType {
        ipVersion dist { IPV4 := IPV4Weight, IPV6 := IPV6Weight, IPVX := (100 - IPV4Weight - IPV6Weight) }
    }
    //Probability of var1 being 1,2,3,4,5 in the ratio 1,2,4,4,4
    constraint cDist1 {
        var1 dist { 1 := 1, 2 := 2, [3:4] := 4 }
    }
    //Probability of var2 being 1,2,3,4,5 is in the ratio 1,2,4/3,4/3,4/3 
    constraint cDist2 {
        var2 dist { 1 := 1, 2 := 2, [3:5] :/ 4 }
    }       
    //Implication constraint - if(channelNum == i) then { ... }
    constraint cImplication {
        (channelNumber == 0) => {
            destAddress in {0:200};
            sourceAddress in {201:400};
        }
        (channelNumber == 1) => {
            destAddress in {201:400};
            sourceAddress in {0:200};
        }
    }
    //Controlling order of constraints solved using a constraint solver
    constraint order_solver {
        solver channelNumber before destAddress;
        solver channelNumber before sourceAddress;
    }

    function new();
        //Setting default min/max packets and min/max packet length
        minNumberOfPackets = 100;
        maxNumberOfPackets = 1000;
        minPacketLength = 128;
        maxPacketLength = 256;
        IPV4Weight = 50;
        IPV6Weight = 30;
    endfunction
endclass
```